# How to fix this ploblem when clone url?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Every time I clone the url from bitbuket I have to add "app password" after "use name" to succeed. How to fix it?

https://(use name):(app password@)bitbucket.org/levandong120896/demo.git

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clone it via terminal first and then add it to SourceTree later.